# Jquery: can you explain this line of code to me? help me to understand it, or give references to where I can learn about it

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

Jquery 1.6 just came out, I grabbed this code from the `.is` api page.
I just had a few questions on a piece of code I saw there:

1) why is `return` needed? Isn't there another way to write this that's easier? I mean, i've never used `return` when I've written anything Jquery. Obviously I haven't written anything advanced and i'm still just learning. **Why would you need it, when would you use it? and is there another way to do the same thing?**

2) `$('strong', this)` means "any `<strong>` elements in this element." **right?** and that full line would read "give me the element that has 2 strong elements within this"? **right? or?** (i think i have that wrong.) **isn't there another way to write this?** i've only seen this used a few times.

```
$("li").click(function() {   
var $li = $(this),
    isWithTwo = $li.is(function() {

      return $('strong', this).length === 2;

    });   
if ( isWithTwo ) {
    $li.css("background-color", "green");   } else {
    $li.css("background-color", "red");   } });
```

Comment: The documentation says: *Using a Function | The second form of this method evaluates expressions related to elements based on a function rather than a selector. For each element, if the function returns `true`, `.is()` returns `true` as well.* What is it that you don't understand now?

Comment: Why would someone use `$('strong', this)`? couldn't they just use `$(this).find('strong')` or something like that? what's the difference? where do I find documentation for this: `$('strong', this)`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same... you can find information here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is return needed?

Look at the [documentation for `is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/). The point is that the function will return either true or false.

> `$('strong', this)` means "any `<strong>` elements in this element." right?

yes

> and that full line would read "give me the element that has 2 strong elements within this"?

No. It will be "If there are 2 strong elements, return true, otherwise return false"

Answer (score 1):

`return $('strong', this).length === 2;`

If `this` has 2 `<strong>` elements, return `true`. Otherwise, return `false`.